# Cannot Receive Unicode Value from input on Python-Flask

Tags: python-2.7, unicode, flask

My Sample Python Script is like this:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from flask import *

app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route('/', methods=['GET','POST'])
def checkName():
    if request.method=='POST':
        namekh = request.form['KhmerName']

        print "Khmer name is ",namekh
        if isinstance(namekh.encode('utf8'), unicode):
            return render_template('hello.html', Name=namekh)
        else:
            namekh = 'Please enter khmer character only'
            return render_template('hello.html', Name=namekh)


    return render_template('hello.html')

if __name__ == '__main__':

    app.run(debug=True)
```

From script above, I tried to received input value from form element name `KhmerName` on submit and check if it is a Unicode Character or not. Then I send it to display at my html markup `hello.html`.

The html is look like this:

```
{% if Name %}
    <p>Hello, {{Name}} wellcome to mysite</p>
{% endif %}
<form class="form-horizontal" action='' method='POST'>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="KhmerName" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Khmer Name:</label>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="KhmerName" name="KhmerName" placeholder="KhmerName">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

However, my problem is that if `KhmerName` is kind of None-Character is it working fine, yet it is an Unicode Character, it will return an error message

```
UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode characters in position 0-4: character maps to <undefined>

Traceback (most recent call last)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1997, in __call__
return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1985, in wsgi_app
response = self.handle_exception(e)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1540, in handle_exception
reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1982, in wsgi_app
response = self.full_dispatch_request()
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1614, in full_dispatch_request
rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1517, in handle_user_exception
reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1612, in full_dispatch_request
rv = self.dispatch_request()
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1598, in dispatch_request
return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
File "F:\python\check Unicode\hello.py", line 12, in hello_world
print "Khmer name is ",namekh
File "C:\Python27\lib\encodings\cp437.py", line 12, in encode
return codecs.charmap_encode(input,errors,encoding_map)
UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode characters in position 0-4: character maps to <undefined>
```

What I did to check the Unicode here is by using `isinstance(namekh.encode('utf8'), unicode)`, so it should working (return true) because the type of `namekh` was already an `unicode` type if an input value was an unicode character. Yet, I had no idea why it return an error like above.

Comment: Can you provide an example of `namekh` that throws the error?

Comment: @andrew_reece, i.e `namekh='សួរស្តីរ'`

Comment: After `encode`, you get a variable which type is `str` in Python2.

Comment: @stamaimer, if in interactive console, I got it type as `str` using `type(namekh)`; however if input value is from web brower (html markup), it throw an error `UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode characters in position 0-4: character maps to <undefined>`

Comment: Can you provide the whole stacktrace?

Comment: @stamaimer, sure, please refer to my question edited. Thanks

Comment: From the traceback, The exception is raise in the `print` statement. Try to use `print "Khmer name is ", namekh.encode("utf-8")`

Comment: @stamaimer, I will test that case by case such unicode+none-unicode character, thanks.

Comment: @stamaimer, following you, I tried this `namekh = request.form['KhmerName']`, `NameKhmer = namekh.encode("utf-8")`, `isinstance(NameKhmer, unicode)`, it can print character in unicode in interactive console, but my `if condition` at `if isinstance(NameKhmer, unicode):` still returned `False` meaning `NameKhmer` still not recognize as a unicode type yet after encode. Thanks

Comment: I have already said through the traceback you provide the exception is raise in the `print` statement before you `encode` the variable. And I also said 
 `encode` will return a `str` object instead of a `unicode`. That's why the check of `isinstance` is `False`.

Comment: @stamaimer, how can I covert type to unicode ? I tried this 'khmerName=unicode(namekh.encode("utf-8"))' but still raise an expection.

Comment: At first. figure out the type of `namekh`. If it's a unicode you needn't do anything, If it's a str you can use `decode` to decode a bytes to unicode with corresponding encoding.

Comment: @stamaimer, thanks, could you help make it as an answer? so I will check it as an answer and try it out,

Comment: @stamaimer In python3 he doesn't need to do anything but the question is tagged python2 so he needs to decode it into unicode first as strings are necessarily a sequence of bytes in python2 and the characters he has given `សួរស្តីរ` these cannot be represented by sequence of single byte .

Comment: @0decimal0 I have test on my demo project with py2. Please see my answer.

Comment: @stamaimer there you use an already decoded string so it will be valid,but here user takes the characters which are not decoded so he has to .

Comment: @0decimal0 I have already test `សួរស្តីរ` on my demo project. The data transform between browser and server is binary stream(bytes). But what you get from `request.form["key"]` of flask is unicode instead of bytes. So decode on it is pointless. It's already a unicode object.

Comment: @stamaimer Even if `request.form['key']` returns unicode it is still string and not a sequence of characters but a sequence of bytes and cannot be represented in python2 and the code is still python , flask is just a framework

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have test on a demo project. The type of variable return from `request.form["key"]` is `unicode`. So you needn't transform it to `unicode` from `str` use `decode`. I also test `សួរស្តីរ` on the demo project, it can be printed. From the code you provide. You might want to only allow the khmer character. I think you use regex to test the input.

```
REGEX_KHMER = u"[\u1780-\u17dd\u17e0-\u17e9\u17f0-\u17f9]+"

if re.match(REGEX_KHMER, namekh):

    return correctly

else:

    return enter khmer character only
```

Comment: it works in the opposite way, by entering Khmer character, it return `please enter khmer character only`, otherwise, it return `correct`. I went on trying to decode it like this `namekh = namekh_old.decode('utf-8')` and got the error `UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position 0-3: ordinal not in range(128)`.

Comment: `decode` is operate on `str` instead of `unicode`. You haven't understand the relation between `unicode` and `str` and the relation between `encode` and `decode`. I have provide the method of use regex to limit the input from user.

Comment: as I inspected the `if re.match(REGEX_KHMER, namekh):` when entering khmer character, it return `None`, otherwise it return at match at position[..]. that way worked differently from what expected.

Comment: So find the reason why it worked differently from what you want.

Comment: @HouyNarun I have update my answer. It must be only allow khmer character in namekh.

Comment: I have tested your answer and it works great, thanks very much for your help. I might need to read and understand about this topic especial about unicode encoding and decoding plus regular expression. Anyway, thanks very much :)

Answer (score 0):

**Edit- My earlier answer was a bad one. I am improving it**

The characters in `សួរស្តីរ` cannot be represented by single bytes and as in python2 string is a sequence of bytes you will have problems.

Truth is, you can **decode into unicode**(*in python-2.x `str` is a sequence of bytes you have to decode it into unicode,you don't need that in python-3.x as the strings are already in unicode,they are `str` objects- sequence of characters or if I may say character abstractions*) and **you can only encode into bytes not decode it**.

Actually as @stamaimer suggests the data returned from `request.form["key"]` in flask is in `unicode` So you don't need to encode it infact you can't and that is why you get the error.

You can just do like :

```
isinstance(namekh,unicode)
```

No need to encode. But it doesn't make sense either because you already have unicode.

Comment: very much thanks, I will try test that and let you know.

Comment: it does not work, `isinstance(namekh, unicode)` was returning `false`. Thanks

Comment: @stamaimer Yes of course , but only if they can be represented . Here the namekh gets a `string`  and `string` is not an unicode object in python2 , it is in python3. Its not even possible to represent it as a sequence of bytes. Check my comment at the question. It clarifies it.

Comment: Why it can't be represented as a bytes? In my answer, I have already list the codepoint of unicode of khmer character. We can encode them to `str`(bytes).

Comment: It's a conflict in your statements. You said namek is a str(bytes) is not an unicode object. You also said it can't be represented as a bytes. So what is it?

Comment: I don't think one and every character of that string can be represented by a single byte, it may take two probably three . On my system `isinstance ("សួរស្តីរ", unicode) ` returns false on python2. There is no conflict in my statement there are only `0-255` numbers which can be used to represent a character in a byte and I am pretty sure those are not those characters. They will probably need two or three bytes per character so how can they be represented in python2 unless they are decoded.

Comment: I have never said use a single byte to represented khmer character. It determined by the encode algorithm. The result of `isinstance("សួរស្តីរ", unicode` is false because you create a str instead of an unicode object.

Comment: You said "it's not even possible to represent it as a **sequence of bytes**". And please distinguish the difference between byte and bytes.

Comment: I meant one byte per character.

Comment: The problem is not here. How many bytes to represent a character is depend on the codepoint and the encode algorithm you use.

Comment: Very much thanks for your helpful comments and answers, I understood the point that the `request.form['key']` is always a unicode type, therefore `isinstance(namekh,unicode)` is nothing; it always return `true` whatever the input character is. That wasn't answer to my question as I would need to know whether the input character is an unicode character (Khmer Character) or none-unicode character. Finally, I came up with  solution like this, though it is not perfect one,`try: namekh = str(namekh) return 'not unicode' except: if isinstance(namekh, unicode): return 'unicode'`.

Comment: I hope that by unicode characters you mean non-ascii characters, because every known character can be a unicode character. Your above solution still makes no sense to me because all `str(namekh)` does is return a string which is printable representation of the object  `namekh` ,i.e sequence of bytes .

Answer (score -1):

I hope this can help you.

```
@app.route('/', methods=['GET','POST'])
def checkName():
    if request.method=='POST':
        namekh = request.form['KhmerName']

        print "Khmer name is ",namekh
        # The default namekh is unicode
        if isinstance(namekh, unicode):
            return render_template('hello.html', Name=namekh)
        else:
            namekh = 'Please enter khmer character only'
            return render_template('hello.html', Name=namekh)


    return render_template('hello.html')
```

[as follows](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CXh2F.png)

Comment: The type of `request.from["key"]` is `unicode`. It doesn't make sense to do `isinstance(namekh, unicode)`.

Comment: @stamaimer Actually I got your point . `request.from["key"]` does return unicode , I checked it out, so it really doesn't make any sense to compare it but it isn't wrong either.

Comment: @0decimal0 But use it as the condition is wrong in the code logical.